# c# не получается вызвать функцию из DLL библиотеки написанную на Haskell

Tags: c#

Не получается вызвать функцию из DLL библиотеки.

Поместил DLL, созданную на Haskell, в одну папку с проектом, который написан на c#.
Саму библиотеку он находит, но не функции в ней. Предполагаю, что неправильная сигнатура.
При вызове выдает ошибку о том, что название функции не найдено.

Ошибка:
(Unhandled exception. System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'adder' in DLL 'Foo.dll'.)

Код подключаемой библиотеки:

```
module Foo where

adder :: Int -> Int -> IO Int
adder x y = return (x+y)

foreign export stdcall adder :: Int -> Int -> IO Int
```

Код основной программы:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestXascel
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("Foo.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr adder(IntPtr x, IntPtr y);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ok");
            adder((IntPtr)5, (IntPtr)2);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Я знаю, что можно подключить и другим способом, но нужно именно этот.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11756773/5376639

Comment: DllImport вроде как предназначен для импорта функций "неуправляемых" сборок (т.е. unmanaged dll). В то время как dll, скомпилированные с языка C# - управляемые сборки. Вы занимаетесь чем-то не тем. Какую цель вы преследуете?

Comment: Я пробовал подключать на примере c#, вообще мне нужно получить функцию из dll написанной на языке Haskell и Python

Comment: Плохой пример. C# создает DLL с управляемыми сборками, они загружаются не так, как у вас, а с использованием функции Assembly.Load. Нужно DLL написать на другом языке, тогда пример, скорее всего, будет работать. Про интреоп с пайтоном вообще много где написано

Comment: На счет Пайтона спасибо, к нему я еще не приступал. Но у меня тек же есть библиотека написанная на Haskell и она точно так же не работает как и та что на c#, ошибка точно такая же.

Comment: Покажите таблицу экспорта DLL, полученную одним из способов отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4438900/8674428

Comment: А почему `IntPrt`? По-моему, в C# должно быть `int`.

Comment: [Вызов Haskell из C#](https://coderoad.ru/16615641/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-Haskell-%D0%B8%D0%B7-C)